# Reconfiguring python

Tags: python, makefile, configure, compiler-flags

I installed Python-2.7.3 with `configure --enable-shared`, `make` and `install`.
It so happens that now, I need to reconfigure to include the `--with-pydebug` option.

While running `configure` again, do I need to include all the flags I had before? (`--enable-shared`) or is it okay to `configure` again with just the additional flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`configure` configures the build from scratch (with minimal support for caching certain results). Therefore, you need to supply all the same flags as before.

When changing configure flags, it is also recommended to do a `make distclean` to ensure that everything is rebuilt. This is especially important with `--with-pydebug` since the basic `PyObject` layout will change.

Comment: And if interested, I think you can grep the original configure command out of `config.log`...

Comment: @mgilson: yes, this is very good advice especially if you've lost the original configure command. You can also find all of the environment settings in `config.log` in case you had to tweak e.g. the compiler path.

Comment: It seems to me that there was an easier way to get it, but I can't seem to remember what it was (or even if it actually exists) off the top of my head ...

Comment: Well, the command is usually near the top of `config.log`. So you don't usually need `grep`, just `less`.